# Finding missing numbers with python

Tags: python

Python is a hobby I'm learning in my spare time so sorry for the convoluted question. I have a challenge project that I'm supposed to solve where I find a possible range of missing values in a sequence.  For example, if there are five people and we know the heights of three of them and their sequence, can we find a range of heights for the two unknowns. Then can we check new names on whether they could possibly be the missing person.

Index, Name, Inches

> 1 John 67

> 2 ?, ?

> 3 Ralph 75

> 4 ?, ?

> 5 Gregg 79

The rule is the people are listed from shortest to tallest height. So #2 must be equal to or greater than #1 and equal to or less than #3. Just looking at this, I can solve it without code.

#2 is 67 to 75 inches tall

#4 is 75 to 79 inches tall

If the two additional names and heights were Matt (79) and Harry (68) I can solve the problem as the sequence is John, Harry, Ralph, Matt, Gregg. I guess what I'm really trying to ask is does Harry fit into any of the possible ranges?

But for a beginner, it is hard to code because sometimes you are given value 1, 2, 3 and need to solve for 4 and 5.

I have tried a bunch of different ways and haven't come close.  Even a link to another question similar to this would be fantastic. Edited to add one person who won't fit either range to make it clear I'm trying to account for that situation as well.

```
Sarah = 64 
Harry = 68
Matt = 79
name_list = [[1, John, 67], [3, Ralph, 75], [5, Gregg, 79]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to always think about all the possible cases, not just the ones given, as the correct solution has to work right no matter what the data is.  What I figured is that you will have a bunch of people you know the heights of, and some that for some reason you kinda/sorta know the heights of because you know their height is between two people whos height you know.  But there's no reason to expect that you'll always have a missing person between each pair of heights you know. So you have to represent your unknowns in your data as well as your knowns to prevent false positives.  A missing person has a height of 0.

I like to do test driven development, so I put together a test first that my code has to pass. I wanted to test the situation where there is a missing person whose height falls outside of the range of known heights.  To test both conditions, there is no missing person with a height below all the known heights, but there is a missing person whose height is taller than all the known heights.

Here's my whole solution, including a set of test that I believe handle all the cases:

```
def could_be_missing_person(knowns, person):
    person_age = person[1]
    for i in range(len(knowns)):
        if knowns[i][1] == 0: # Is this an entry for a missing person?
            if i == 0 and person_age < knowns[i+1][1]: # height below all known heights
                return True
            elif i == len(knowns) - 1 and person_age > knowns[i-1][1]: # height above all known heights
                return True
            if knowns[i - 1][1] < person_age < knowns[i + 1][1]:
                return True
    return False

def test(knowns, person):
    r = could_be_missing_person(knowns, person)
    print(person, ": ", r, " <- A possible missing person!" if r else "")
    if person[2] != r:
        print("   WRONG!!!")

knowns = [["John", 67], ["", 0], ["Stan", 73], ["Ralph", 75], ["", 0], ["Gregg", 75],["Jeremy", 79], ["", 0]]

testers = [("Sarah", 64, False),
           ("Harry", 67, False),
           ("Harry", 68, True),
           ("Matt", 74, False),
           ("Richard", 75, False),
           ("Ronald", 76, False),
           ("Ronald", 78, False),
           ("Jimmy", 80, True),
           ("Jimmy", 85, True),
           ]

for p in testers:
    test(knowns, p)
```

Result:

```
('Sarah', 64, False) :  False 
('Harry', 67, False) :  False 
('Harry', 68, True) :  True  <- A possible missing person!
('Matt', 74, False) :  False 
('Richard', 75, False) :  False 
('Ronald', 76, False) :  False 
('Ronald', 78, False) :  False 
('Jimmy', 80, True) :  True  <- A possible missing person!
('Jimmy', 85, True) :  True  <- A possible missing person!
```

I was bored and so I had fun with this.  I like that you're programming for fun.  I hope this improved your experience!

Comment: This is awesome, though I'm still working through could_be_missing_person function to understand what you did.  While I think it will get me moving in the right direction big time (Thank You!), sometimes I get people other than #1, #3, #5.  For example, what if we have Randy 75, Ralph 76, Eric 77 as the knowns. But the question indicates they are #3, #4, and #5 in the sequence.  The testers include Suzy 57, Cindy 79, Alicia 72.  I know that #1 Suzy, #2 Alicia, #3 Rand, #4 Ralph, #5 Eric and Cindy is False since I was solving for #1 and #2. But this is really awesome. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi!  I'm glad you like this.  I'd be happy to go over it with you.  I'm an old timer in terms of programming and it was a hobby for me when I started at 16 or so.  So I love hearing someone saying it's their hobby...that it's just for fun.

Comment: Thinking through the logic wasn't simple for me.  It took some real thinking to get the two end conditions right.  I had a purpose in all of that.   I wanted to give you something more to think about.

Answer (score 0):

the variable names are pointless and just making this more confusing for you. just add the names to the list without their position and let the list sorting keep their index.

```
>>> name_list = [["John", 67], ["Ralph", 75], ["Gregg", 79]]    
>>> name_list.append(["Harry", 68])
>>> name_list.sort(key= lambda x: x[1]) 
>>> name_list
[['John', 67], ['Harry', 68], ['Ralph', 75], ['Gregg', 79]]

>>> for idx, obj in enumerate(name_list, 1):
...      print(idx, *obj)
... 
1 John 67
2 Harry 68
3 Ralph 75
4 Gregg 79
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you get a list something looks like `[(John,67),(Ralph,75),(Gregg,79),(Harry,68),(Matt,79)]`

then, you sort that list with parameter key:

```
list.sort(key=lambda _: _[1])
```

You will have something looks like:
`(John,67),(Harry,68),(Ralph,75),(Gregg,79),(Matt,79)]`

I think this is done!

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to be insertion sorted with tuples rather than single values. You can probably do some research if you want to solve for yourself but this would be a solution:

```
def insert(list, new_person):
    height = new_person[1]
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if list[i][1] > height:
            break
    new_list = list[:i] + [new_person] + list[i:]
    return new_list


sorted_list = [["John", 67], ["Ralph", 75], ["Gregg", 79]]
new_people = [["Sarah", 64], ["Harry", 68], ["Matt", 79]]
updated_list = sorted_list

for person in new_people:
    updated_list = insert(updated_list, person)

print(updated_list)
```